# Javascript Help - my breadcrumbs script to work correctly

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

Can someone take a look at this and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Basically the script is supposed to grab the URL of the page, splits the URL into an array via '/' and then document writes the HTML href link for each subdirectory. It kinda works until there is a webpage that is 2 folders deep from the root, and then it messes up.

If this is the URL for example: `website.com/root/folder/subfolder/page.html` it gives me:

`> Home / Folder / Subfolder / Page`

visually on the page, which is correct. (website.com/root/ is the actual home page.)

The link for 'Home' is correct and takes you to `website.com/root/`.

The second link for 'Folder' is correct and takes you to `website.com/root/folder/`.

However, the third link for 'Subfolder' is wrong and for some reason links to `website.com/root/` again.

It's got to be something on line 14 where it says `getLoc(i-3,subs[i],subs.length)+defp+` but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Here is the script:

```
function breadCrumbs(base,delStr,defp,cStyle,tStyle,dStyle,nl) { 
    tit=document.title.replace(/Ak DRB > /g,"");
    loc=window.location.toString();
    subs=loc.split("/");
    document.write('<strong>></strong> <a href="/drb/" class="'+cStyle+'">Home</a>  '+'<span class="'+dStyle+'">'+delStr+'</span> ');
    if (loc.includes(".html") && !loc.includes("index.html")) {
        a=1;
    }else{
        a=2;
    }
    for (i=4;i<(subs.length-a);i++) {
        SUB=makeCaps(unescape(subs[i]));
        document.write('<a href="'+getLoc(i-3,subs[i],subs.length)+defp+'" class="'+cStyle+'">'+SUB+'</a>  '+'<span class="'+dStyle+'">'+delStr+'</span> ');
    }
    if (nl==1) document.write("<br>");document.write('<span class="'+tStyle+'">'+tit+'</span>');
}
function makeCaps(a) {
  g=a.split(' ');for (l=0;l<g.length;l++) g[l]=g[l].toUpperCase().slice(0,1)+g[l].slice(1);
  return g.join(" ");
}
function getLoc(c,e,f) {
  var d="";
  if (c>0) {
    for (k=0;k<c;k++) d=d+"../";
  }else{
    d="../"+e+"/";
  }
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I got it to work. I just had my relative path structure wrong and was trying to make it too complicated. All you need for the final `getLoc` function is:

```
function getLoc(c,e,f) {
  var d="";
  var g=f-5;

  if (c==g) {
      d="./";
  }else{
      d="../";
  }
  return d;
}
```

Comment: In fact 'e' variable isn't even needed.